# Stacking Surface plots in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

What I have are two sets of data z1 = f1(x,y) and z2 = f2(x,y).
Most generally, My Aim is to plot these functions in order compare them. These functions are quite close to each other which makes plotting them in the same axis a bit of a problem as they overlap quite closely.

The scheme I thought of applying was of plotting z1 and z2 on the same axis, sharing the x and y axis, with z2 plotted a certain amount above z1. something like the figure here

https://www.originlab.com/doc/Tutorials/3D-Stack-Surface
(sorry, wasn't sure if the figure was licenced to be copied here)

Is there any standard way of acheiving this in Matplotlib or using Python plotting libraries in general.

Comment: You can check this out https://problemsolvingwithpython.com/06-Plotting-with-Matplotlib/06.16-3D-Surface-Plots/#3d-surface-plots-with-2d-contour-plot-projections